# SQL Server. How to place select case inside another select with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In advance sorry if my question is repeated or similar to another, I've alreay checked another posts similar to this but I can't get it right.
So, here is my question.
I have the next two select statements, and I have trouble in placing correctly the second query inside the first, I have tried putting inside the select, after the joins, and it'd be awesome if you could help me or give and advice.

```
select distinct movements.date, movements.productcode, products.productname
,clasification.family, clients.clientname, clients.clientcode, documents.invoicereference
,movements.quantity, movements.price, movements.credit, movements.total, movements.exchange
,movements.state, movements.city
from invoices.movements

  inner join invoices.products
  on invoices.movements.idproduct=invoices.products.idproduct
  left outer join invoices.documents
  on invoices.movements.iddocument=invoices.documents.iddocument
  inner join invoices.coins
  on invoices.documents.idcoin=invoices.coins.idcoin
  inner join invoices.address
  on invoices.address.iddocument=invoices.documents.iddocument
  inner join invoices.clasifications
  on invoices.clasifications.family='aspen'
  inner join invoices.clients
  on invoices.documents.idclient=invoices.clients.idclient
```

This is what I get from the previous query.

```
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+-----+----+
|date|product_code|product_name|client_name|client_code|invoice_reference|quantity|unit_price|credit|total|exchange|state|city|
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+-----+----+
```

But I also want to add another column that refers to the type of clients, they have two clasifications, if their client_code is like this 'N00000' (or more specific, if they end with a zero), they're **"Casual"** clients if not (like 'N00013', they're **"Fixed"** clients. Here is the query.

```
select 
  case
   when invoices.clients.idclient='N00000' then 'Casual'
   else 'Fixed'
    end as client_type,
     clientcode, invoices.clients.clientname
from invoices.documents.
inner join invoices.clients
on invoices.documents.idclient=invoices.clients.idclient
```

My problem is that I can't seem to put the query correctly inside the first one, and I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you add your attempt to combine the two queries, and what error message you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aliases are your friend, as is code formatting.

> (or more specific, if they end with a zero)  they're "Casual"

```
select distinct 
    im.date
  , im.productcode
  , ip.productname
  , icla.family
  , icli.clientname
  , icli.clientcode
  , id.invoicereference
  , im.quantity
  , im.price
  , im.credit
  , im.total
  , im.exchange
  , im.state
  , im.city
  , case when id.idclient like '%0' then 'Casual'
         when id.idclient is not null then 'Fixed'
         end as client_type
from invoices.movements im
  inner join invoices.products ip
    on im.idproduct=ip.idproduct
  left outer join invoices.documents id
    on im.iddocument=id.iddocument
  inner join invoices.coins ico
    on id.idcoin=ico.idcoin
  inner join invoices.address
    on invoices.address.iddocument=id.iddocument
  inner join invoices.clasifications icla
    on icla.family='aspen'
  inner join invoices.clients icli
    on id.idclient=icli.idclient
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this fixed my problem. (:

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've already done the necessary join in your first query, so you'd just need to add your CASE expression in the column list of the first query like so:

```
select distinct movements.date, movements.productcode, products.productname
,clasification.family, clients.clientname, clients.clientcode, documents.invoicereference
,movements.quantity, movements.price, movements.credit, movements.total, movements.exchange
,movements.state, movements.city, case
   when invoices.clients.idclient='N00000' then 'Casual'
   else 'Fixed'
    end as client_type
from invoices.movements

  inner join invoices.products
  on invoices.movements.idproduct=invoices.products.idproduct
  left outer join invoices.documents
  on invoices.movements.iddocument=invoices.documents.iddocument
  inner join invoices.coins
  on invoices.documents.idcoin=invoices.coins.idcoin
  inner join invoices.address
  on invoices.address.iddocument=invoices.documents.iddocument
  inner join invoices.clasifications
  on invoices.clasifications.family='aspen'
  inner join invoices.clients
  on invoices.documents.idclient=invoices.clients.idclient
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful (: